# How can I refer to items from a specific level in a list without the previous levels?

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumitem

I have a multilevel list. I would like to be able to sometimes refer to a level two item as 1a, and other times as just a. How can I do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

Here are some questions:

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{Q:WhatIsBlue} What is blue?
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{Q:IsBlueRed} Is blue red?
\item \label{Q:IsBlueYellow} Is blue yellow?
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Question~\ref{Q:IsBlueRed} is a subquestion of question~\ref{Q:WhatIsBlue}. Also, question~\ref{Q:WhatIsBlue} has two parts, \ref{Q:IsBlueRed} and \ref{Q:IsBlueYellow}. It is good that I can refer to question~\ref{Q:IsBlueRed} as \ref{Q:IsBlueRed}, but sometimes I will need to refer to it as just ``a'', not \ref{Q:IsBlueRed}. How can I do this?


\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to have a way of referring to the crossed out items as just a and b, while also preserving the ability to refer to 1a and 1b.

If possible, I do not want to use \ref{Q:WhatIsBlue}\ref{Q:IsBlueRed} because if the second level question "Is blue red?" is moved to another first level question, the reference will no longer makes sense. I would like to be able to move subquestions around without references breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `zref`. It allows you to create additional properties to the label, where you can store just the part of the enumerate subcounter you want, and then refer to it.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{enumii}{\alph{enumii}}
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/begin}{%
  \zref@iflistcontainsprop{main}{enumii}{}{%
    \zref@localaddprop{main}{enumii}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here are some questions:

\begin{enumerate}
\item \zlabel{Q:WhatIsBlue} What is blue?
\begin{enumerate}
\item \zlabel{Q:IsBlueRed} Is blue red?
\item \zlabel{Q:IsBlueYellow} Is blue yellow?
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Question~\zref{Q:IsBlueRed} is a subquestion of
question~\zref{Q:WhatIsBlue}. Also, question~\zref{Q:WhatIsBlue} has two
parts, \zref[enumii]{Q:IsBlueRed} and \zref[enumii]{Q:IsBlueYellow}. It is
good that I can refer to question~\zref{Q:IsBlueRed} as \zref{Q:IsBlueRed},
but sometimes I will need to refer to it as just
``\zref[enumii]{Q:IsBlueRed}'', not \zref{Q:IsBlueRed}. How can I do this?

\end{document}
```

[image]